# System.Web.Helpers.Json case-sensitive deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I've been using System.Web.Helpers.Json to deserialize objects quite successfully up until I received a json with the keys that only differ in case of the letters and the Decode() method throws an ArgumentException. I tried to figure out how to make this class work in case-sensitive way and couldn't. I also tried to experiment with Newtonsoft Json.NET library instead which works fine case-wise, however the differences in decoded results are too great and incompatible with the rest of my code, so I'd prefer to stick with System.Web.Helpers namespace for now.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CaseSensitivityTest() {
  string json = "{\"e\":\"executionReport\",\"E\":1616877261436}";
  dynamic result = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(json);//System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
  Assert.IsTrue(1616877261436 == result.E);
}
```

How would I tell this class to respect the case of json identifiers?

Comment: What is the problem with JSON.Net then? I don't think you'll find too many people to help with the `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode` method since it's very old and has been superseded more than once now.

Comment: The problem with Json.Net is that I will have to rewrite the rest of my code to adapt to the changes of the parsed results. I tried to make a wrapper, but the differences are too great and I'm afraid I will miss some subtle difference that will make a great deal of change in production. For instance I recently encountered that Json.Net will fail to deserialize json file with big integer values. This is not something I wrote a test for, and I had to debug to actually find this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to replicate a part of System.Web.Helpers stack to discover that the issue is with [line 22 of DynamicJsonObject](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.Helpers/DynamicJsonObject.cs#L22) which goes like this:

```
_values = values.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => Json.WrapObject(p.Value),
StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

This is not configurable, so there's no way to change it in settings. As a workaround I created replicas of DynamicHelper, DynamicJavaScriptConverter, DynamicJsonObject and Json classes changing that one line above to use `StringComparer.Ordinal` instead.